# Philosophie des Geistes - Sprachphilosophie - common rules to merge substantives

Tags: word-choice

Are there rules or is it just a relict of history and convention if substantives are merged? "Philosophie des Geistes" is a distinct discipline and so a proper name. But then there is also "Sprachphilosophie". Would it be correct/o.k. to say "Geistphilosophie"?

Are there more general rules when and how to merge substantives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the solution already in your question: building merged nouns is case sensitive. By using genitive we may build:

> Geistesphilosophie

in analogy to *"Geistesgegenwart*", *"Geistesblitz"* etc.

There are some sources that use the term *"Geistesphilosphie"* but it seems not to be widely accepted and is not listed in the Duden.

Comment: It may also be interesting to have a look at [Google ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Philosophie+des+Geistes%2CGeistesphilosophie&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

Comment: +1 *zeitgeist* also fits your rule @fuz i have to bookmark this ngrams thing etymology swiss knife :)

Comment: I almost included an ngram shot to the answer - but then I thought this  may be overload. I like google ngrams but keep in mind they may be biased.